# Custom context processors don't work in Django 1.8.2

Tags: python, django

When you load a page with global variable (which should be set and accessible through context via main/context_processors.py), the rendering engine ignores global_item, like if it was not set.
But local variables work fine, as they usually do.

`views.py`:

```
def global_item(request):
    time = datetime.now()
    context = {
        'time': time,
    }
    return render_to_response(
        'main/global.html',
        context
    )
```

`context_processors.py`:

```
def global_item(request):
    global_item = "global item"
    return {
        'global_item': global_item,
    }
```

`global.html`:

```
<p>
  {{ time }}<br>
  {{ global_item }}
</p>
```

And while rendering it drops `global_item`: [screenshot](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/13184998/8511399/e99ab324-231c-11e5-9a65-0a285f089bdd.png)

Also, I added a line `'main.context_processors.global_item',` to `'context_processors'` in `settinds.py`.

Why isn't it working?

Explore repo on GitHub: https://github.com/yerohin/context_processors_test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using a RequestContext to render your template. Request processors don't run with a normal context.

Instead of using `render_to_response`, use the `render` shortcut, which takes `request` as the first parameter and uses a RequestContext internally:

```
return render(request, 'main/global.html', context)
```

This is nothing to do with the Django version, though.